# Can't add to a List of int?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I am getting crazy on this. How come i can't add int to this list? It sounds so simple.

```
private List<int> StepToRemoveForportfolio
{
    get
    {
        object obj = this.ViewState["stepToRemoveForportfolioForStep"];
        if (obj == null)
        {
            List<int> mylist = new List<int>();
            return mylist;
        }
        else
            return (List<int>)obj;
    }
    set
    {
        { this.ViewState["stepToRemoveForportfolioForStep"] = value; }
    }
}
```

And somewhere else i do :

```
test.Text += "id = " + _id + "<br>";
StepToRemoveForportfolio.Add(_id);
test.Text += "count : " + StepToRemoveForportfolio.Count + " <br>";
```

I get as a result:

```
id = 1500
count : 0
```

I am obviously missing something. 
Thank you

Comment: The part you are missing is that the setter will never be called.  It is creating a new `List<int>` every time you call `StepToRemoveForportfolio`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    if (obj == null)
    {
        List<int> mylist = new List<int>();

        this.ViewState["stepToRemoveForportfolioForStep"] = mylist ;


        return mylist;
    }
```